# jQuery Image Slider CSS not resizing on iPad but cuts off

Tags: jquery, css

I'm using the same jQuery image slider on two sites and one site is correctly resizing while the other is cutting the slider off when viewed on a iPad/Safari browser.  I've tried to emulate the CSS of the working site but still can't figure it out.  Any ideas?

Photo Slider Works here: http://tinyurl.com/42ww9c6

Broke here:  http://tinyurl.com/creb29o

Comment: On the broken, what's the size of the images and what's the desired size?

Comment: 940x541 is the size of the photos

Comment: And what do you want it to be?

Comment: I just want the entire page to show right now it is cutting the right side of the photo slider off like this:  http://www.progresstechnologies.com/photo.png

Comment: Would you mind putting the code in PasteBin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I could deduce from your `style.css`, `#content-sidebar-wrap` is being overridden. 
When I played with it in Safari I found that doing the following fixed the issue:

```
#content-sidebar-wrap {
float: left;
width: 947px !important; 
}
```

I used `!important` to prevent it from being overridden.